# Get a list of all objects grails is planning to magically save

Tags: session, grails, save, grails-orm

If I make a domain object in a controller and don't call `.save()`, Grails will do it for me automatically at some point. I am creating lots of domain objects without planning to save all of them and getting 'references an unsaved transient instance' exceptions when my service exits.

How would I get a list of all objects that Grails will try to save when the controller/service exits so that I could prevent some of them from being saved?

Answer (score 3):

You're better off retrieving instances that you know you will edit but don't want persisted with the `read` method instead of `get`. Using `read` doesn't make it read-only, since if you call `save()` and it was modified it will be persisted, but it won't be auto-persisted when the OSIV interceptor flushes the session.

Another option (especially if the instance isn't individually loaded) is to remove it from the session using `detach()` while you're editing it.

You could also use DTOs and copy the data into those non-persistent classes so you're not mucking with persistent classes, just data classes that Hibernate doesn't know about.

Comment: I'm talking about objects I make with `new SomeDomainClass()` but then didn't actually want.

Comment: Also, based on your "use DTOs" comment can you check out my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918276/grails-can-i-use-domain-objects-when-i-dont-want-to-save-anything

Comment: Burt, I feel like sometimes I come off rude to you, and less than enthusiastic about grails.  This could not be farther from how I feel.  You rock, thanks for answering so many of my questions.

Comment: New instances are never automatically saved - Hibernate doesn't know anything about them until they're associated with the session, and that only happens when they're attached via a `save()` call. There is cascaded saving with collections when you use `addToFoo`, but I assume that's not what you're talking about.